# Using string from array as key in object with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm using a for loop to get strings from an array. I need to use these strings as object keys.

This code works when run but TypeScript complains:

```
const arr = ['one', 'two'];

const map = {
    one: 'Vaue is 1',
    two: 'Value is 2'
}

for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const item = arr[i];
    const res = map[item]
    console.log(res)
}
```

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ one: string; two: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ one: string; two: string; }'.(7053)
```

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know that `item` is a valid key of `map`? As the error tells you, the type is inferred as `string`, and there are plenty of strings that are neither `'one'` nor `'two'`. Can you give `arr` a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to declare `arr` as const. For example:

```
const arr = ['one', 'two'] as const;

const map = {
    one: 'Vaue is 1',
    two: 'Value is 2'
}

for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const item = arr[i]; // "one" | "two"
    const res = map[item]
    console.log(res)
}
```

Another solution, if the array needs to be based on the map, is to type `arr` as a collection of keys of `map`:

```
const map = {
    one: 'Vaue is 1',
    two: 'Value is 2'
}

const arr: (keyof typeof map)[] = ['one', 'two'];

for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const item = arr[i]; // "one" | "two"
    const res = map[item]
    console.log(res)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the compiler at least type for on of your variables `map` or `arr`.

Option 1. Type Array:

```
const map = {
  one: 'Vaue is 1',
  two: 'Value is 2',
};

const arr: (keyof typeof map)[] = ['one', 'two'];
```

This way we make sure that `arr` can only contain `map`'s keys

Option 2. Type map:

```
const map2: Record<string, unknown> = {
  one: 'Vaue is 1',
  two: 'Value is 2',
};

const arr2 = ['one', 'two'];
```

We just tell that `map` has any string key and that does the trick.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/PTAEHkAUBUElwHKgIwChUGMD2A7AzgC6gC2AhgA6gC8oA3qqKLgKYBcoA5AGqkCuzoAJZ4UHADQNQBAO5Z23UgBt+QkQCZxqAL4BudNnxFSAJ2PsAFAGtmATywAzKTfLMHJCgEoA2gF1qoLw4WcU4ZLA4fPVR7LGNQc0VmIkF-AAYdIVAAHlATYwA6RJwAcwIACwzBAGoqjzpJA0IhAmZifzyvQUiG3CbjZhEaMnJOluJuxkasRMKsYvN+vA89LXQQCBh4JDV9XqJhtXYAJWZsYwATLMJjQRKxUF4cSxwsaRwAPn96RhZ5HhVhKIJIwwn8lAD1JpdLtDLlTGp-IFgvcOGEIlEYnEEklMjR0pkcnk1IVmCVypUanVvqBGskxu14Z0JjS9qBFv4DqNWsypjNFHMFgNltpUEA)

Answer (score 0):

you can declare this keys as a type, check this out:

```
type KeysMap = 'one' | 'two';

const arr: KeysMap[] = ['one', 'two'];

const map = {
 one: 'Vaue is 1',
 two: 'Value is 2'
}

for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const item = arr[i];
  const res = map[item]
  console.log(res)
}
```

this way typescript knows that the type options are equal to the map keys

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, as the message says, typescript doesn't know that the items in `arr` will match a key of `map`. Therefore, you need to define in your code that `arr` is an array with keys of the type `map`:

```
const arr: (keyof typeof map)[] = ['one', 'two'];
```